# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select tab by number in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, editor, jetbrains-ide

I would like to be able select the first tab with ⌘1, second tab with ⌘2, and so on, just like I would in Atom or web browser.

I couldn't find a way using PyCharm settings, is there some way to do it?

Comment: GoToTabs plugin does the job!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way navigate through opened tabs with keyboard is:

1. by using <kbd>LEFT</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> KEY to swich to the left or right.
2. or by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter *switcher*.